Max Length of subarray with length equal to sum of its elements
The problem is to find maximum length of subarray with length equal to sum of elements in that subarray.
For example:
input_arr = [16, -1, 3, -7, 2, 8, 11, 24]
output_arr = [-1, 3, -7, 2, 8]

Here output_arr has sum 5 which is equal to its length.
The solution I wrote uses idea of prefix sum, where we store the current prefix sum in a hashmap and for any index check if the residual sum exist in this hashmap.
    int longestSubarray(int n, vector<int> &arr) {
        unordered_map<long long,int> m;
        int maxLen = -1;
        long long currSum=0;
        
        m[0]=-1;
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            currSum+=arr[i];
            
            if (currSum==i+1){
                maxLen = max(maxLen, i+1);
            }
            else if (m.find(currSum-(i+1))!=m.end()){
                maxLen = max(maxLen, i-m[currSum-(i+1)]);
            }
            else m[currSum]=i;  // Line J
        }
        
        return maxLen;
    }

Doubt here is in the Line J, that is usually we keep track of current prefix sum currSum. But for this specific problem, storing currSum-(i+1) gives correct answer. I cannot make sense out of why storing the remaining sum in hashmap will help, unlike other prefix sum problems.

What's your question?

How keeping track of currSum-(i+1) instead of currSum   at Line J in code, helps in getting the correct answer?

You say "the solution I wrote", but I don't think it's possible to write this code without knowing the answer to your question.  This is a clever little algorithm.

This problem is similar to the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/description/, where in we keep track of sum seen so far. But for my problem, keeping track of remaining sum currSum-(i+1) gives correct answer. I am not able to justify, why changing Line J to  m[currSum-(i+1)]=i helps.

How did you come up with that if you don't understand it?

Let array [j, i] has sum arr[j] + ... + arr[i] = prefix_sum[i] - prefix_sum[j -1] and has length (i-j+1). So, we need to check prefix_sum[i] - prefix_sum[j-1] == i - j  + 1. Note that prefix_sum[i] is sum of subarray from [0,i] which has length i+1. Then we need to store prefix_sum[i] - (i+1) in map with index i.
Note that we store the smallest index for each prefix_sum[i] - (i+1) as i.
In the loop, if we get index k such that prefix_sum[k] - (k+1) exists in hash, we got map[prefix_sum[k] - (k+1)] = i. Then the length of subarray is k - i.
Lastly, we get maximum for all length like this.
